# How to convert Foreach loop to Linq (in datagridview)

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in gridView.Rows)
{ // Access the CheckBox 
    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("SuburbSelector");
    if (cb.Checked)
    {
        //do something;
    }
}
```

I tried the following and got error

Linq:

```
var Str = SuburbGridView.Rows.Cast<GridViewRow>().Where(r=>(CheckBox)r.FindControl("SuburbSelector")==checked);
```

Error:

> Delegate 'System.Func < System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRow,int,bool>' does not take 1 arguments

Many thanks

Comment: Do you need the cast SuburbGridView.Rows.Cast<GridViewRow>(),  isn't Rows already anm IEnumerable<GridViewRow> ? Also you should be careful about a null on return from FindControl or a static cast exception if a control is misnamed.

Comment: Unfortunately the type of `GridView.Rows` is `GridViewRowCollection`, and it only implements `IEnumerable` (the non-generic one), not `IEnumerable<GridViewRow>`, so the type param can't be figured out automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linq doesn't seem to have a good "each" aggregate.  There is `Aggregate()`, which I don't like if I'm not actually accumulating anything, since the accumulator value is essentially thrown away.  I don't think there's anything equivalent to `List<T>.ForEach()`, and it's a shame.  If you're using C# 4.0, and don't mind processing in parallel, you could use `.AsParallel().ForAll()`.  So anyway, here's a few ways to do what you want:

Using `List.ForEach()`:

```
SuburbGridView.Rows.Cast<GridViewRow>().Where(
    r => ((CheckBox)r.FindControl("SuburbSelector")).Checked).ToList().ForEach(row =>
{
    Response.Write(row.ID);
    // Do something
});
```

And using Parallel Linq:

```
SuburbGridView.Rows.Cast<GridViewRow>().Where(
    r => ((CheckBox)r.FindControl("SuburbSelector")).Checked).AsParallel().ForAll(row =>
{
    Response.Write(row.ID);
    // Do something
});
```

I'm just getting the hang of this LINQ stuff myself.  I love it.

By the way, you were just missing an extra pair of `()`'s around your cast.  `FindControl()` returns a `System.Web.UI.Control`, and you have to cast it to `CheckBox` to access the `Checked` property.  You can't do it like this:

```
// Doesn't work
(CheckBox)row.FindControl("someCheckbox").Checked
```

That doesn't work because of the order of operations.  The `.Checked` is evaluated before the cast to `CheckBox`, which means you're trying to access a `CheckBox` property of `Control`, and it doesn't exist.  The extra pair of parens fixes that.

```
// Works
((CheckBox)row.FindControl("someCheckbox")).Checked
```

And one last thing, you don't need to do `== true` in your comparison.  `Checked` is already a boolean value.  If you like it there for clarity (some people do), then by all means keep it.  It's not considered bad practice or anything, it's just a matter of preference.

Answer (score 1):

You need `.` instead of `=` towards the end:

```
var Str = SuburbGridView.Rows.Cast<GridViewRow>()
          .Where(r=>((CheckBox)r.FindControl("SuburbSelector")).checked);
```

I can't be sure that's the only bug, since you didn't indicate what error you got.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work:

```
var result = SuburbGridView.Rows.Cast<GridViewRow>().Where(r => ((CheckBox)r.FindControl("SuburbSelector")).Checked);
```

What error are you getting?

Comment: Delegate 'System.Func<System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRow,int,bool>' does not take 1 arguments